# iOS app not displaying correctly iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I am working on an App which should be able to run on iPhones and iPads.
I have been able to run it on iPhones and it is displaying perfectly. But when I run it on an iPad the App itself is very zoomed in. I am not sure what main issue.

**This is how it displays on iPad:**

[image]

**And this is how it comes up on an iPhone:**

[image]

Any idea how to fix it or what the issue is?

Comment: Is it a universal app or an iPhone only app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app isn't made to run on the iPad. When displayed on the iPad, it just stretches the display of the iPhone version (you can see that by the 1x button on the lower right corner of the screen). You need to setup your XCode project as a Universal App (instead of it being just for iPhone) and then you'll be able to take advantage of the entire iPad screen and design the display especially for it.

You can set the app as Universal on your project properties in XCode:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did try that. but when I set it up as universal and then run it on an iPad it comes up with blank white screen. It doesnt show my app. It only shows the launch screen and after then blank white screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to check the size and position constraints on all of your subviews (if you're using auto layout). When running on an iPad, your views have more space and you probably want a different display for the iPhone and the iPad and therefore need to position your view differently. You can user auto layout and size classes for that, and in rare cases, you can even create separate .xib files for use on the iPhone and the iPad.

Comment: does this have anything to do with the "Any width / Any Height " settings at the bottom of the Xcode? Should I set it to any width and any height and design my app that way?

Comment: If you want the screen layout to look relatively similar on all devices (iPhones and iPads), maybe on different sizes, I would start with that. Also, try looking for more AutoLayout information. There are a lot of good tutorials on the subject that can guide you in the right direction. But first, start with turning your app into a Universal app, if you want it to display properly on an iPad and use all of the screen size... :-)